# how to get map object from placemark position in yandex map kit android studio

Tags: android, dictionary

how to get map object from placemark position in yandex map kit android studio
private fun addMarkers(
latitude: Double,
longitude: Double,
imageProvider: ImageProvider
) {
// should get mapObject and check mark position MapObjectTapListener
binding.mapview.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(Point(latitude, longitude), imageProvider)
placemarkMapObject = mapObjectCollection.addPlacemark(Point(latitude, longitude), imageProvider)
placemarkMapObject.addTapListener(mapObjectTapListener)
}

private val mapObjectTapListener = MapObjectTapListener { mapObject, point ->
// check mapObject
true
}

I have no idea
private val mapObjectTapListener = MapObjectTapListener { mapObject, point ->
// check mapObject and open info dialog
true
}